# Explain the VMware Tanzu Kubernetes grid networking requirement

Tags: kubernetes, tanzu-application-service

I am trying to setup a tanzu kubernetes grid cluster and need help in clerification and creation of network required for setting up the tanzu kubernetes grid cluster
I have one ESXI and did the setup of vcenter on it

Can we use NSX-T for setting up the tanzu kubernetes grid and if yes, then how to do the setup ?

cluster should get created once all the setup is done

I creted networks and tried a do setup on it but it is failing so not able to understand whether i am missing something